# Authentication failed for Azure Git

Tags: git, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to clone my webapp in Azure.

When I run `git clone https://username@appname.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/appname.git` the terminal asks me for my password.

But when I fill in my password, it keeps saying that the authentication has failed.

Even though I changed my password plenty of times in the Portal (Settings -> Set deployment credentials).

Any reason it keeps saying that my authentication has failed?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I had the same problem with my site and it turned out the issue is with the site url:
the automatically generated remote url was: https://user@site.scm.azurewebsites.net/site.git

On the other hand the portal showed: [https://user@site.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/site.git](https://user@site.scm.azurewebsites.net/site.git)

After updating the remote url in git with the following command:

```
git remote set-url azure
https://<user>@<site>.scm.azurewebsites.net/<site>.git
https://<user>@<site>.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/<site>.git
```

things started working as expected.

The morale of the story: check the deployment url as well as the password.

Comment: Are you sure that was 433 and not 443?

Comment: I had to change out our Orgs name for my user name and then generate an alias and it worked fine.

Comment: The larger moral of the story is to not use microsoft products

Answer (score 125):

Yes many of the answers here are pointing to the correct path, but my case:-  I was given a url to access git repos on azure cloud for which I'm perfectly fine to access/browse the code on browser (*Vs*) when I'm trying to clone I've got the same issue.

So when you click on **clone** as shown in below image, you've got to Generate Git credentials; this is weird, not sure why, probably they've setup my account to access azure cloud, which can't be used to clone git repos(means can't be used as git credentials). This is something different from what I've seen with AWS/gitlab/bitbucket, maybe an issue with account setup, or if it's common thing for repos on Azure and if you're in same issue - give it a try. [image]

Another one, as everyone has already mentioned, please don't try to connect to url which is produced over there (something looks like):

```
https://project-account@dev.azure.com/project-name/apps/_git/library/
```

Instead try to connect thru your GIT username and then use password:

```
https://username@dev.azure.com/project-name/apps/_git/library/
```

As a tip: if your username has special characters in it, Git cmd/bash will throw errors, so replace those with valid characters, ex. :-

1. **@ can be replaced with %40**
2. **+ can be replaced with %2B**

something like :  `https://username%40xyz.com@dev.azure.com/project-name/apps/_git/library/`

Comment: Effing hell this was hard to spot, why do they generate a url that messes up pushes?

Comment: Alternatively if you don't want to do as like given above (**HTTPS** way of cloning- which is mostly used), You can try this **SSH** thing as well ::: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=current-page , I've tried it recently which will work either way..

Comment: In my case I just generated the credentials and used the generated password and it worked for me.

Comment: Godtier answer.  Why would they give us a URL that doesn't work lol?

Comment: Thanks - as a multi-year user of Github this wasn't intuitive that ADO requires you to use credentials from the "Generate Git credentials" button. Once I used those, it worked perfectly. Thanks again!

Answer (score 14):

Accepted answer did not work for me but this worked.

1. Check your set Azure URL with

   ```
   git config --get remote.<azure-remote-name>.url
   ```
2. Reset azure url with following command

   ```
   git remote set-url <azure-remote-name>
   https://<user>@<sitename>[_<slotName>].scm.azurewebsites.net:443/<site>.git
   ```
3. Try pushing your code using

   ```
   git push <azure-remote-name>
   ```
4. It will open windows authentication screen which says to enter credential to connect to `https://<user>@<sitename>[_<slotName>].scm.azurewebsites.net/<site>.git`
5. Cancel this window. It will prompt the basic credential window which says to enter credential to connect to `https://<user>@<sitename>[_<slotName>].scm.azurewebsites.net:433/<site>.git`

Enter in your credential and it works.

Comment: same here. thanks for sharing! yours is the only solutions that works for me

Comment: To add: the end of the generated url said ...:443/.project.git, but pushing only seems to work with ....443/.git

Comment: worked for me, make sure you cancel the credential window, and enter in the password in the terminal

Comment: Thanks! For some reason, this popup does not appear when pushing from within Visual Studio.

Comment: error: invalid key: https://dev.azure.com ...

Answer (score 7):

1. Login into Azure Dev Ops portal.
2. Go to Project you wish to clone.
3. Select Repo from left menu.
4. Click on Clone from right top corner.
5. Click Generate Git Credential
6. Enter given username & password where you are cloning repository.
7. you are done!

Answer (score 6):

Since `azure` does not support ssh you will have to use your password at least once (in some cases you will not be prompt for password next time)

Here is an article describe how to set it up

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/

And here is how to set up git with Azure:
http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/building-and-deploying-windows-azure-web-sites-using-git-and-github-for-windows

---

**Here are the steps that you followed**

> If this is your first time setting up a repository in Azure, you need to create **login credentials for it**.
>
> You will use them to log into the Azure repository and push changes from your local Git repository. From your web app's blade, click `Settings > Deployment credentials`, then configure your deployment username and password.
>
> When you're done, click OK.

#### Now do this:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem when try to `git clone https://<username>@praat.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/<repo-name>.git` . I solved the problem by removing the port.

So your new url should not have the port **443**.

Answer (score 4):

None of the above solution worked for me.

> The reason why the same error was observed in my deployment was
>   because my password contained a character "@".

This malformed the Git clone url for my Azure web app. When I changed my password by removing @, it solved this issue. You can change @ to `%40` in your connection string as well.

Answer (score 3):

[**Current Azure Structure for adding credential**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvgl1.png)

Use the highlighted user, password, confirm password section to create an user credential. Use this to proceed where you were stuck.

Answer (score 2):

I had to do it this way

1. Generate Git Credentials
2. `git remote add origin https://username:password@dev.azure.com/xxx/_git/xxx`
3. `git add.`
4. `git commit -m init`
5. `push -u origin --all`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're entering the correct password each time, it might be a delay/propagation issue.

You can also use your **Site-Level credentials** as detailed on [this wiki page](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-credentials). You can get these by downloading your publishing credentials in the Portal via the "Get Publish Profile" option on your main WebApp bar. The user name / password can then be found in the `yourapp.PublishSettings` file and will look something like `userName="$yourapp" userPWD="ABC123"`. This is only mentioned as a workaround if your **User-Level** credentials are not working (which they should be if they are correct).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where the automatically generated git clone url was:

```
https://group-admin-account-username@dev.azure.com/site.git
```

So instead I had to replace this with my own account username

```
https://my-username@dev.azure.com/site.git
```

This then prompted me for the password for my account correctly:

```
git clone https://my-username@dev.azure.com/site.git
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is I created personal access token. 
Click username in top right corner > Security > Select Personal Access token from left pane > New Token.
Provide token name and scope for your token and Click create. 
Save that token and use it as password.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error in Visual studio because I used the sync feature when the branch hadn't been created in 'https://dev.azure.com/foo/bar' yet.

Instead of doing a sync, I did a push & then it prompted me for my credentials.   After that it worked fine.

Hopefully this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

If you unable to clone the projects/repos,

- Check proxy settings or VPN if provided
- Check repository path access
- Check your access or password expiry

If you are facing login issue,

- Generate PAT (Personal Access token) for respective version control system like Git, Azure etc.
- If PAT fails, create alternate credentials
- If this both are right and still you are unable to access then

  1. Goto your repository click on **Clone** button, there you can find **Generate Credentials** button. Try to login with those newly generated credentials.

Check for all above options first. If you are following everything and still facing issues then try to take help from colleagues/team leader/ manager or client.

Answer (score 1):

Adding token before dev.azure in URL settings worked for me. I am using SourceTree.

```
https://token@dev.azure.com/org/_git/repo
```

Comment: Where do you get this token?

Comment: I have issued mine here: https://dev.azure.com/MY_ORGANIZATION/_usersSettings/tokens

Answer (score 1):

Go to Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Credential Manager
and click Add a Generic Credential
and add URL LINK only Domain
and add user name & password
Finished.

git add .
git commit -m "init"
git remote add origin YourUrlRepo
git push -u origin -all

Answer (score 0):

A straight forward method to get this over with is to Download/Get Publish profile (make sure you refresh the portal page) from main toolbar and use the password given in the .publishsettings file.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a matter of cloning the project with the remote url and cancelling the windows security prompt. Afterwards, it'll ask you for the password.
Once you're able to clone it, you can push it successfully.

Moral of the story: Clone it first before pushing.

Answer (score 0):

On mine, the password was never created when I set the deployment user from the cli.  I had to go to the web app, app services, for the app, then set the deployment credentials

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Security Tab >> Personal Access Tokens >> New Toke >> Give it **Full Access** >> Note the Access token as you will use it as your password

Answer (score 0):

this may help: with my first webapp, i had to go to Deployment Center, Deployment Credentials. And then use either the App Credentials or create User Credentials. After this, delete the cached credentials on the local machine (windows: Control Panel\User Accounts\Credential Manager). run "git push webapp master:master" again, enter either of the Deployment Credentials. That worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case none of the above methods solved my issue (but they directed me to find out where I'm going wrong)

I tried both auto generated App credentials and my custom created user credentials, and every time I was getting authentication failed message.

The description on the credentials page was advising me to have the username in the following format:

`<app-name>\<username>`

This was why authentication failed. As soon as I put my username without the `<app-name>` prefix the authentication passed and everything worked smoothly.

Hope this information helps

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the **Deployment Center** >> **Deployment Credentials**, there will be application credentials for local git. Use the username and password there will work.

Answer (score 0):

Using SSH instead of HTTPS worked for me after adding my SSH key

Answer (score 0):

Some of the above brought me close, such as the post by @Nilay Vishwakarma but I finally found the cause of my authentication issue to be that my password contained a '$' followed by a '..u7' which I eventually noticed in powershell was highlighted yellow when I typed.

I thus assumed it could be the CLi has an issue with this character in passwords (even though it wasn't mentioned as a reserved character in [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-dotnetcore-sqldb-app?pivots=platform-linux#configure-local-git-deployment)).

I re-ran the 'az webapp deployment user set --user-name [user] --password [pwd]' command with a revised password without the '$' and was able to then enter my credentials and authenticate.

Comment: Having a `$` at the begining of the password could cause the same issue, but I don't thing that this was the issue of the author of the question

Comment: Thanks - I get that but the authentication error message was the same, hence how I ended up here.
It appears from other comments that there are various issues which will result in the same error, so since the password I entered was not accepted due to the '...$...' I considered it relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Using Mac I had the same issue. Using Git Credential manager worked.

- Installed GCM using brew https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core
- Connected git to remote Azure Repo
- On git push, pop up requested username and password
- All connected.

Don't be surprised when you see PAT (Personal Access Token) in you settings.

"Once authenticated, the credential manager creates and caches a personal access token for future connections to the repo. Git commands that connect to this account won't prompt for user credentials until the token expires. A token can be revoked through Azure Repos."

Below link should help

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/set-up-credential-managers?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Sourcetree and you tried all of the answers here and nothing works.

try **cloning** your project again using this url structure as source:

```
https://<username>:<password>@dev.azure.com/project-name/apps/_git/library/
```

username and password comes from the **Generate Git Credentials** button when you clone your branch.

Answer (score 0):

I suddenly had the same problem. It turned out to be a problem with my local station and the **Internet adapter** being rejected leading to not authenticated. **Disabling IPV6** solved the problem for me: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69712045/7302498

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem because of saved login info in Macbook.

1. I entered Key Chain Access App of Mac.
2. Then, I found login info under login, opened it.
3. I updated password with my **Credential Password** of Azure Repo. (*Click* "*Generate Git Credentials*")
4. Done! Now, I can pull my branch in SourceTree.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to provide the Personal Access Token (PAT) that was created when I created a new Azure Organization, instead of any password. This PAT needs to be saved by you since it will not be available later after you close the PAT screen.

I had forgotten my PAT and had to regenerate it and provide it for the Git login, for this issue to resolve.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to enable `SCM Basic Auth Publishing Credentials` on Configuration tab

Answer (score -1):

In my case it looks like azure server is slowing down.

Git deployment

git push azure master

fatal: Authentication failed for

FTP deployment

Authentification - OK upload speed 1-10K