# How to resolve fatal: Authentication failed for git [bitbucket]

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-tower

I have been facing issue when i fetch or pull in any client. i.e "Tower" and Sourcetree. Everything was going smoothly , i did just update macos into Mojave.

But I always get

> Error details:  fatal: Authentication failed for
>   'https://username@bitbucket.org/sample/sample.git/'

Comment: Can you login via browser? What command did you exactly use?

Comment: Yes i am able to login via browser. even i used this command on terminal "git credential fill" and put info in this template: $ git credential fill

protocol=https 
host=(https://bitbucket.org/sample/sample.git)
username=user123
password=pass123

Comment: Which template? Please show the result of `git remote show origin` (You can edit your question!)

Comment: When i command "git remote show origin" it asked password i entered password then it shows origin branches at terminal

Comment: Then you need to show the exact sequence of commands (and output) which lead to the error above. Otherwise I can't help.

Comment: I did just remote origin, using terminal command "git remote remove origin" and then put command again "git remote add origin https://myusername@bitbucket.org/project/project.git" and now its fetching in Tower (MacOs Client).

Comment: I did resolve that issue with removing origin and then add origin. after that i was using tower and sourcetree tools in macOsMojave. after this all, i was having issue like when i fetch from origin. not an single tracked branch was updating status. I just remove tracking of branches and then add tracking again. after that its working fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this solution:

```
git remote add origin https://{username}:{password}@github.com/{username}/project.git
```

Comment: This will save you secret username/password in the plain text gitconfig file. The OP should use a credential manager, and needs to upgrade to the very latest version.

Comment: Agree with @Philip. The username/password will also be in plain text in your shell history. This should be avoided.

Answer (score 11):

The same error (Windows, Git Bash command line, bitbucket). Using https (not ssh) which should prompt for login credentials but instead errors:

```
$ git pull origin master
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://bitbucket.../my_git_project.git'
```

```
$ git config -l
...
credential.helper=manager
...

$ git config --global --unset credential.helper
$ git config --system --unset credential.helper
```

`git pull` now prompted for username/password.

Comment: better and clear answer than originally accepted answer.

Comment: Incase you don't know your password, [follow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70528023/7296835) copy the password and paste. boom

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to use the Git Credentials Manager (https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/releases/tag/v1.18.1), or the appropriate cred manager for your OS. Don't put your username/password in the plain text config file (unless it is double blank..)

Comment: I did resolve that issue with removing origin and then add origin. after that i was using tower and sourcetree tools in macOsMojave. after this all, i was having issue like when i fetch from origin. not an single tracked branch was updating status. I just remove tracking of branches and then add tracking again. after that its working fine.