# Git TypeInitializationException while pushing code to branch

Tags: git, git-bash

I am trying to push code to the my remote branch. I get the below error logs.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type
initializer for 'Microsoft.Alm.Cli.Program' threw an exception.
--->
System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException: External component has
thrown an exception.    
  at AzureDevOps.Authentication.TokenScope.op_BitwiseOr(TokenScope left, TokenScope right)    
  at Microsoft.Alm.Cli.Program..cctor()    
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    
at Microsoft.Alm.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args) 
  fatal: Authentication failed for
'https://dev.azure.com/ubplDevOps/ConnectrixCompanyAndroidApp/_git/ConnectrixCompanyAndroidApp/'
```

When I send the push command, a password popup opens up but when I enter my password it gives the above error. I can login to my account on web using the same password but it's not allowing me to push .

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with Git itself. It's some sort of Azure-specific authentication issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if, when you are cloning the Azure repository, you see the option "Generate Git Credentials", as [`seen here`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56956726/6309)

Check also the remote URL used:

```
git config --get remote.<azure-remote-name>.url
# or simply
git remote -v

# check the URL referring to azure
```

If it has the project account in it, replace that URL with your Azure username (the one used when you login to your Azure account).

---

> I was working on the same repository for around 2 months. Yesterday it started giving this error.

There are no [recent Azure incidents](https://status.azure.com/en-us/status/history/), so try and change your password, to see if that reset has an influence on your current issue

---

The [OP Vivek Mishra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4562287/vivek-mishra) points [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59979386/git-typeinitializationexception-while-pushing-code-to-branch/59979578?noredirect=1#comment106075989_59979578) to [personal access tokens](http://[), which in the OP's case has expired.

> Azure has some personal access token, that was expired for my user.
>   I regenerated that token and added and it started working

That was [introduced in 2018](https://blog.devmatter.com/the-new-pat-experience/), and does include an expiration date.

[image: https://blog.devmatter.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/NewPATScreen-1024x649.png]

Comment: I was working on the same repository for around 2 months. Yesterday it started giving this error.

Comment: What do I pass in azure-remote-name ?

Comment: `git remote -v` returned the correct url of my repository

Comment: @VivekMishra Does it include the same login you are using to login on web?

Comment: `-v` only returned the url. It's not showing any login information used

Comment: @VivekMishra THen check if the last part of https://stackoverflow.com/a/56956726/6309 helps.

Comment: I was able to push using the generated password from the link that you shared. Do I have to do this everytime I have to push ?

Comment: I got the solution. Azure has some personal access token, that was expired for my user. I regenerated that token and added and it started working

Comment: @VivekMishra Great! I have included your comment in the answer, for more visibility. I have added some links to the official documentation.