# fatal: unable to access 'https://dev.azure.com/xxx': OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection was reset in connection to dev.azure.com:443

Tags: git, azure

I've been working with a repo in Azure for months without any issue, but recently started getting this error intermittently when I try to update my remotes or push/pull:

OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection was reset in connection to dev.azure.com:443

If I keep retrying, it will eventually work. No idea what is causing this.

Things I've tried:

- Updated Git
- Turned off firewall
- Tried on a different computer with no issues

Comment: Based on: 1.) If you keep retrying (and presumably with no other changes), it eventually works. And 2.) Works fine from another machine. This leads me to believe the problem is likely not related to Git or Azure, and is instead a networking issue on the problem machine. Maybe touchy wi-fi or a bad network cable? One thing to check, at the exact moment it isn't working, is that machine able to access other things on the internet without any problems?

Comment: I'm guessing you're going to say that internet works fine even while the problem is happening... and if so, *intermittent* networking issues could possibly be a bad route somewhere. When the problem is happening, try pinging dev.azure.com and see if you can hit it and get a response. Also try when it's working and compare (both IPs and and response).

Answer (score 90):

This seems to have something to do with IPv6 - you can disable it by doing the following:

1. Go to View **Network Connections**

   [image: View Network Connections]
2. Right click on your current network and select **Properties**

   [image: Network Properties]
3. **Deselect IPv6** Internet Prorotcol Version 6

   [image: Internet Prorotcol Version 6]

Comment: Surprisingly, Silver and Grilse's answers didn't work for me, but this did.  However, it did **require a reboot**.

Comment: This worked for me and didn't require a reboot

Comment: It works for me too. Does someone knows why disabling IPv6 fixes that issue?

Comment: This had been causing me problems for ages and the hosts file wouldn't fix it for me. Thanks.  ps not noticed any difference since disabling it.

Comment: As of 03/2023 this is still a valid solution

Comment: Worked for me as of August 2023, didn't require a reboot.

Comment: Same, AUgust 2023, worked for me. Thanks for saving my work day!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 29):

This seems to be related to IPv6.
When I disable IPv6, the connection works. When I re-enable IPv6, it's broken again.

I've disabled IPv6 for dev.azure.com by editing my hosts-file. This way, everything works.

> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

```sh
# Workaround for git connection errors
# fatal: unable to access 'https://dev.azure.com/MyOrg/my-project/_git/my-repo/': OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection was reset in connection to dev.azure.com:443
# https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/cannot-connect-to-devazurecom-nor-azuremicrosoftco/1189016
13.107.42.20  dev.azure.com
```

The IPv4 address of dev.azure.com may change in the future, please verify it and adjust as necessary.

#### Further Reading

- [OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection was reset in connection to dev.azure.com:443](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/openssl-ssl-connect-connection-was-reset-in-connec/1305123)
- [Cannot connect to dev.azure.com nor azure.microsoft.com](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/cannot-connect-to-devazurecom-nor-azuremicrosoftco/1189016)

Comment: Thanks a lot to you and @KyleMit. We just experienced this issue with one of our team members as well. We disabled IPv6 on their machine entirely like Kyle suggested, issue was instantly resolved.

Answer (score 10):

I also noticed turning off IPv6 fixed the issue. However it was actually caused by the wireless driver.

It turned out to be 'Killer Prioritization Engine" which is part of the drivers for the Intel wireless card. Turning this feature off in the 'Killer Intelligence Center' fixed the problem and let me use IPv6.

Comment: This worked for me. Just had the issue after an update to the Killer suite. IPV6 is still enabled. If you have an Intel wireless card, this could be the issue.

Comment: I really wasn't expecting to find a solution to this problem but this fixed it exactly. Oddly I would only experience the connection resets from my home network, never from my work network.

Comment: This was the problem for me too. Instead of leaving the Prioritization Engine turned off, I downloaded the newest Intel drivers that include the Killer Intelligence Center.

Answer (score 7):

On Windows 10 and 11, this worked for me:

`git config --global --unset https.proxy`

`git config --global --unset http.proxy`

Answer (score 3):

Problem randomly showed up when everything was working fine the minute before:

```
$ git push origin master
fatal: unable to access 'https://dev.azure.com/xxx': OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection was reset in connection to dev.azure.com:443
```

The cause is unknown (and no longer interested to dig that up) but this is the solution that worked for me:

1. Run in cmd prompt: `tracert www.dev.azure.com`
2. Prompt shows: `Tracing route to l-0011.l-msedge.net [aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd]`
3. In Windows, navigate to: `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`
4. Modify `hosts` file in Notepad++ (Run as Admin to save).
5. Add line: `aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd dev.azure.com`

I can push again after.

#### Further Reading

- [Find the IP Address of a Website Using Command Prompt](https://www.instructables.com/Find-the-IP-address-of-a-website-using-command-pro/)
- [git push error: OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection was reset](https://www.programmersought.com/article/63977437566/)

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, still not sure why

```
git fetch --all;
git pull --all;
```

now commands like `git pull` and `git push` will work.

Comment: Are the semi-colon included in the commands?

Comment: you do not need the semicolons if you run them one at a time they just make it so copy and pasting will work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing this in Windows 10. On a whim I went into Network Settings for my internet connection, Network profile, and changed from **Public** to **Private**. Git pull worked immediately.

Answer (score 1):

I was the same problem with my repositories but before exchange to github i updating git bash to version 2.33.1 and back to work.

Dont forget update to git version (2.33.1)
Disable protocol IPV6 at your Network Properties

Answer (score 1):

I thought this should be updated, as there's also issue for us who are behind a corporate firewall and proxy. PowerShell and/or Terminal need to be configured to accept the proxy configuration before you can connect.

Instructions on how to do this are here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/devops/git-clone-push-operation-failing-devops-repo?source=recommendations

This worked for me.