# private vnet: Git clone my azure repo from Azure ML compute instance is impossible

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-virtual-network, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-nsg

Since a few days, I try to clone my Azure Devops repo in my Azure ML compute instance but I can't do it.
In fact, I am in my private network with a private compute instance.

So obviously I have to create rules in my network security group to allow in/outbound to https 443.
However... It doesn't work. I tried everything, even the AzureDevops service tag with a multitude of ports.

My terminal after git clone https:

```
Immediate connect fail for xxxx:1ec:21::20: Network is unreachable
Failed to connect to dev.azure.com port 443: Connection timed out
```

Does anyone have a solution please?

Answer (score 0):

As you want to clone your Azure Repo from your Azure ML compute instance, which is hosted in a private network, you need to add an outbound port rule from your Azure ML compute instance to allow port 443 for internet from your Azure ML instance

You can add outbound port rule as below:

[image]

Still if you get the same error, you can refer the below SO thread for troubleshooting:

[git - fatal: unable to access 'https://dev.azure.com/xxx': OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection was reset in connection to dev.azure.com:443 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67230241/fatal-unable-to-access-https-dev-azure-com-xxx-openssl-ssl-connect-connec)