# Deployment to Azure web app display Error: fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://xxx.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/xxx.git/'

Tags: node.js, azure, authentication, visual-studio-code, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to deploy my node.js application to azure web app using Azure App Service management extension via vs code.
I succeeded to deploy this application many times until two days ago.
Since then I am getting the error log:

***WARNING: Ignoring deploySubPath "." for non-zip deploy.
xxx: Starting deployment...
xxx: Deploying Local Git repository to "xxx"...
Error: fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://xxx.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/xxx.git/'***

At the Azure portal under the Activity log I am getting:
Operation name: Publish Web App
Status: Succeeded

However, At the Deployment center -> Logs:
I cannot see the new deployment.

Any ideas for what should I do?

Note:
[Authentication failed for Azure Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837173/authentication-failed-for-azure-git)

I able to clone an Azure git repository without any problem.
The problem appears when I am trying to deploy my node.js project to Azure App Services using LocalGit in vs code.

When I am looking at the Azure portal -> Deployment Center -> Logs: I cant see the new branch appears on the deployment history

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Authentication failed for Azure Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837173/authentication-failed-for-azure-git)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42830318/getting-fatal-authentication-failed-error-when-sending-git-commands-in-windo